# On which Stackexchange website should I ask about mobile applications?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, mobile-web

As the title say, I want to ask about a mobile app (from a user perspective). My first idea was **SuperUser**, but its "offtopic list" includes smartphones, so that seems like a no-go.

**Android Enthusiasts**, **Windows Phone** and **ThinkDifferent** are too narrow (I want to ask for every platform).

Basically, I'm looking for the equivalent of **Web Applications** for mobile applications. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is one yet.

Maybe this Area51 proposal is what you are looking for:

- [Mobile Devices](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60741/mobile-devices)

> Proposed Q&A site for mobile devices support and questions.

Comment: Ummm, I don't think electronic gadgets should be in that list as it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ask for every platform

The only questions I can think of that would apply to an app, or multiple apps, on *every* platform, would be User Experience questions, for which we have [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

But of course I might just be having a failure of imagination...